# Сортировка массива в разные стороны

Tags: c++, массивы

Реализовать функцию для обработки массива целых чисел.
Функция находит минимальный элемент массива и сортирует все элементы левее его по убыванию, а правее его – по возрастанию. Функция возвращает индекс минимального элемента.Где ошибка?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int SelectSort(int mas[], int size );
int main(){
    int size;
    cin>>size;
    int *mas = new int[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        cin>>mas[i];

    cout << "Index = " << SelectSort(mas, size) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << mas[i] << "\t";

    return 0;
}
int SelectSort(int* mas, int size){
    ///////////////ПОИСК МИНИМАЛЬНОГО ЭЛЕМЕНТА МАССИВА
    int min = mas[0];
    int index;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(mas[i] < min){
            min = mas[i];
            index = i;
    }
    ///////////////СОРТИРОВКА С НАЧАЛА ДО ЭЛЕМЕНТА ПО УБЫВАНИЮ
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        for(int k=index-1;k>i;k--){
            if(mas[k]>mas[k-1]){
                int tmp=mas[k-1];
                mas[k-1]=mas[k];
                mas[k]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    ///////////////СОРТИРОВКА С ЭЛЕМЕНТА ДО КОНЦА ПО ВОЗРАСТАНИЮ
    for(int i=index+1;i<size-1;i++){
        for(int k=size-1;k>index;k--){
            if(mas[k]<mas[k-1]){
                int tmp=mas[k-1];
                mas[k-1]=mas[k];
                mas[k]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    //////////////////////////
        return index;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал запустить ваш код, пришлось исправить, но слишком много ошибок, написал реализацию ниже через STL. И не забывайте освобождать память int *mas = new int[size]; .. delete[] mas;

Comment: Много ошибок — это преувеличение. Там всего одна несчастная пропущенная скобка перед вторым комментарием.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более подходящая реализация:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> SelectSort(const std::vector<int>& inputVector);

int main(){
    std::vector<int> srcVec = {100, 25, 200, -10, 45, 20, 100};

    std::vector<int> dstVec = SelectSort(srcVec);

    for(int item : dstVec) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::vector<int> SelectSort(const std::vector<int>& inputVector){

    std::vector<int> outputVector(inputVector);

    std::vector<int>::iterator minItemIter = std::min_element(begin(outputVector), end(outputVector));
    std::sort(begin(outputVector), minItemIter, std::greater<int>());
    std::sort(minItemIter + 1, end(outputVector), std::less<int>());
    return outputVector;
}
```

Исправленный ваш код:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int SelectSort(int* mas, int size);

int main(){
    const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 7;
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {100, 25, 200, -10, 45, 20, 100};

    cout << "Index = " << SelectSort(array, ARRAY_SIZE) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        cout << array[i] << "\t";

    return 0;
}

int SelectSort(int* mas, int size)
{
    ///////////////ПОИСК МИНИМАЛЬНОГО ЭЛЕМЕНТА МАССИВА
    int min = mas[0];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(mas[i] < min)
        {
            min = mas[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    ///////////////СОРТИРОВКА С НАЧАЛА ДО ЭЛЕМЕНТА ПО УБЫВАНИЮ
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        for(int k=index-1;k>i;k--){
            if(mas[k]>mas[k-1]){
                int tmp=mas[k-1];
                mas[k-1]=mas[k];
                mas[k]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    ///////////////СОРТИРОВКА С ЭЛЕМЕНТА ДО КОНЦА ПО ВОЗРАСТАНИЮ
    for(int i=index+1;i<size-1;i++){
        for(int k=size-1;k>index;k--){
            if(mas[k]<mas[k-1]){
                int tmp=mas[k-1];
                mas[k-1]=mas[k];
                mas[k]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    //////////////////////////  
    return index;
}
```

Comment: а можете не через STL написать, а просто исправить ошибки, если не трудно, просто я еще новичок

Comment: напутали со скобками. Исправленный вариант выше